# Acting with all rational rotations on a subset of the circle having positive measure do you fill almost the whole circle?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, measure-theory

Set $\Gamma$ for the group of the roots of the identity: $\Gamma=\{z\in \Bbb C | z^n=1$, for some $n\geq 0\}$ and for $E\subset S^1$ set 
$\Gamma E=\{z\zeta, z\in \Gamma, \zeta\in E \}$

A trivial but very frequently used fact is that if $E$ is open then $\Gamma E=S^1$.

A measure-theoretic version of that is the following

QUESTION. If $E$ has positive Lebesgue measure, does $\Gamma E$ have measure $2\pi$?

Comment: If there is a counterexample, E can be taken to be a union of orbits of Gamma without being of full measure. I think one can show a la Vitali that such an E is non-measurable, but I am unsure. If not, consider Bernstein sets.  Gerhard "Taking Measure Of This Question" Paseman, 2020.04.25.

Comment: By the aswer of Nik Weaver we have the same result for any infinite  $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 14):

An easy way to see this is by using the Lebesgue density theorem. Any set of positive measure has a density point $t$ (indeed, almost every element of the set is a density point). This means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an interval $I$ containing $t$ such that $m(E \cap I) > (1-\epsilon)m(I)$. This pretty much immediately implies that $m(\Gamma E) > (1-\epsilon)2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please explain better the last step? In particular which lower bound you have for $m(I)$?

Comment: $I$ is an interval of the circle and $m(I)$ is its arc length ... not sure what you're asking.

Comment: In the first $4,5$ rows of your answer you tell us what are density points as we learnt in the kindergarten. The last $0,5+0,5$ rows are the conclusion which should be proved. Where is  the proof? The only nontrivial step  is that $m(E \cap I) > (1-\epsilon)m(I)$ implies $m(\Gamma E) > (1-\epsilon)2\pi$. But this is absent. Could you write, please, an extended proof of that?

Comment: Okay, if you learned about density points in kindergarten then you really shouldn't have trouble with this last very easy step. Hint: if $m(E\cap I) > (1-\epsilon)m(I)$ then $m(\Gamma E\cap I') > (1-\epsilon)m(I)$ for any arc $I'$ of the same length as $I$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $S$ be the circle with Haar-Lebesgue measure and let $G$ be the group of rotations of $S$ through angles that are rational multiples of $\pi$. The action of $G$ is ergodic (according to pg. 69 in *The Legacy of John von Neumann*
edited by James Glimm, John Impagliazzo, Isadore Singer).

So for any measurable subset $E\subset S$ of positive measure, $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$.

Comment: "The action of G is ergodic " Does this mean that for any $E\subset S$ either $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$, either $m(\Gamma E)=0$ ?(sorry about my inculture)

Comment: @jcdornano It means that any positive non full-measure set must map to a larger measure set under the action of $G$, and this in turn implies $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but what i mean by "does it mean ..." is if one can quickly deduce from ergodicity  that we cannot have   $0<m(\Gamma E)< 2\pi$  for some $E\subset S$.  If not, is it true?

Comment: An action is ergodic if the only sets $E$ which are mapped to themselves (up to zero measure sets) are either of full or zero measure. Since rational rotations include the identity, $E\subset \Gamma E$, and so for $E$ of neither full nor zero measure,  $m(\Gamma E)>m(E)$. But this shows in turn that $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$ by repetition.

Comment: No claims here about the nonmeasurable case. Maybe ask your question separately?

Comment: sorry i deleted the bad comment. i will ask a new  question and might continue the discution in the chat , if you don't mind....

Comment: if $m(E)=0$ $m(\Gamma E)=0$  by sigma additivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107197/discussion-between-jcdornano-and-josiah-park).

Comment: I just found this proof. Take a sequence $\Bbb Q\ni x_n\to x\notin\Bbb Q$ and set $R_n$ and $R$ for the rotations of angles $x_n$ and $x$. Set $f$ for the characteristic function of $\Gamma E$. Use continuity of the $L_1$ norm $||\cdot||$ with respect to rotations and have $m(\Gamma E)=||f||=||f\circ R_n||\to ||f\circ R||=m[R(\Gamma E)]$. The sequence on the left is constant! Thus $\Gamma E$ has stable measure under the action of $R$ which is ergodic. Hence $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$ because 
$m(\Gamma E)>0$

Comment: So, according with Josiah Park a gave a problem which is already at page 69 of a book. I Really apologize! I am going to give an harder one

Answer (score 0):

I just found this proof. Take a sequence $\Bbb Q\ni x_n\to x\notin\Bbb Q$ and set $R_n$ and $R$ for the rotations of angles $x_n$ and $x$. Set $f$ for the characteristic function of $\Gamma E$, hence $f\circ R_n=f$ . Use continuity of the $L_1$ norm $||\cdot||$ with respect to rotations, so for $n\to\infty$ we have  $m(\Gamma E)=||f||=||f\circ R_n||\to ||f\circ R||=m[R(\Gamma E)]$. Thus $\Gamma E$ has stable measure under the action of $R$ which is ergodic. Hence $m(\Gamma E)=2\pi$ because 
$m(\Gamma E)>0$