# Acting with a finite number of rotations on a set of positive measure can you fill almost the whole circle?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset S^1$ have positive Lebesgue measure. Do there exist *finitely many* rotations 
$r_1, r_2, \dots ,r_n$ such that $r_1E\cup r_2E\cup \dots\cup r_nE$  has measure $2\pi$? Or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is no. Take a compact set $E$ with positive measure buth empty interior and assume that $K=r_1 E\cup r_2 E \cdots \cup r_n E$ has measure $2\pi$. Then $K$ would be dense in $S^1$, hence equal to $S^1$, since it is closed. But this is impossible, since $K$ has empty interior, too.

Comment: Do you have an exmple of a compact set with positive mesure but empty interior?

Comment: You can take a Cantor set of positive measure

Comment: Of course  I wanted to delete my comment   but to late, you answered already.  Also, your  answer to the main question is very nice!

Comment: Nice answer! What can be said if we relax the condition to: for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $n$ rotations such that $r_1E\cup\ldots r_nE$ has measure greater than $2\pi-\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Capublanca Thanks. In that case it is true, by a limit argument, since using a countable dense set of rotations one can cover almost all the circle (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358506/acting-with-all-rational-rotations-on-a-subset-of-the-circle-having-positive-mea).